# How to change UIView size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I need to update UIView size.

Now i use

```
var titleSize = CGRectMake(0, 30, 40 , 1000)

self.contentCoverScrollView.frame = titleSize
```

in viewDidLoad, but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout in your project?

Comment: Yes but This view not have any Constrain.

Answer (score 4):

In Autolayout if you want to change the frame then try the constraints (`IBOutlet` of `NSLayoutConstraint`).

[image]

Set the constraint outlets and change `constant` value by :

```
self.sampleConstraint.constant = 20
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you had used the AutoLayout in your application that's why it can not change the view frame, please write the below code.

```
var titleSize = CGRectMake(0, 30, 40 , 1000)

self.contentCoverScrollView.frame = titleSize

[self.contentCoverScrollView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Note : updateConstraintsIfNeeded will tell the system to recalculate the constraints in that particular moment of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want to change ScrollView size use:

```
[self.contentCoverScrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(40, 1000))];
```

Comment: In Swift: 
`self.contentCoverScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:40, height: 1000)`

Comment: This is not a ScrollView just Uiview sorry for confusing.